# Why does it say "0 new answers"?

Tags: bug, status-declined

I was just looking at a question and writing an answer when it said "2 new answers". So I clicked on it and 3 answers appeared (I guess the new answers tab just refreshs the frame and while it was refreshing a third answer was submitted). But a few seconds later the tab appeared again stating "0 new answers" and when I clicked it it disappeared and nothing else happened.

I obviously can't reproduce it myself but I am pretty sure that it *is* reproducable.

Sadly I haven't got any screenshot of that behaviour because I immediately dismissed it when I saw it (can't reproduce it myself) but it's just the regular "x new answers" tab with x being zero, which obviously makes no sense.

Comment: Sounds like an uncommon race.

Comment: @Oded Yeah its probably really really unlikely to happen but its still a bug.

Comment: And we are unlikely to fix it.

Comment: I think this happened also to me (a while ago). I quiclky clicked it away but, if I recall correctly, it was the same bug.

Comment: this happens to me as well.. i always get *0 answers* on the LHS (votes / answers/views box), when I click on the actual question, I find out that there are many answers / views / comments. this doesn't seem like a browser issue.

Comment: @TheLostMind it sounds like you're describing something different: by "on the LHS", do you mean the question lists?

Comment: @MarcGravell - yes.. I've indeed faced what the O/P has faced (inside the actual question's page.).. I am also pointing out that outside, in the questions list page (newest usually), I face the problem in which the box to the left of the question doesn't update to reflect the actual number of views/ answers.

Comment: @TheLostMind yes, that is expected behaviour; that updates with refresh only, or if the post is re-announced (the "click to show", or whatever) due to edit

Comment: I have a feeling what happened with this was the "0" was going to be a "1" for the third answer, but you already had that answer up. So it still showed the tab, just with "0"